# Vercel Serverless functions send response cookie

Tags: node.js, cookies, vercel

I want to send an 'httpOnly' cookie with my response from Vercel serverless functions. I am NOT using Express.

I tried `` res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", `ck=${cookie_value}`); ``

This doesn't work. How do I send cookies and put an expiry time on it?

Comment: Did you find a way to set the cooki? Please share it with us.

Answer (score 8):

The standard Node.js [`setHeader`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value) works with the standard [`Set-Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header.

Try using an array like this:

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ['ck=value; Expires=Tue, 01 Dec 2020 00:00:00 GMT; HttpOnly']);
  res.end('It worked, check your cookies in devtools');
}
```

For a nicer interface, you might try installing the [`cookie`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) package.

```
const { serialize } = require('cookie')

module.exports = (req, res) => {
  const cookie = serialize('ck', 'value', {httpOnly: true, expires: new Date('2020-12-01')})
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [cookie]);
  res.end('It worked, check your cookies in devtools');
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me in Vercel serverless. The cookie is just being sent as a part of body.

Comment: Did you get it to work. This serverless stuff is a waste of time. It's not practical and it seems rushed to market.

Comment: No. I just sent the accessToken as a part of response. Incorrect but, Sadly, I don't know what else can be done.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just needed to change the Expire date for it to show. Didn't try the cookie library but will do that next.